# Converting a project from 2.4.3 to 3.0.X with the build.gradle file?

Tags: grails, gradle, grails-3.0

So I'm working on converting a grails 2.4.3 project to grails 3. Our reason for the upgrade is because of a unit test issue that's fixed in grails 3.

I started this process and followed the steps on the offical documentation for grails 3 when migrating from a previous version of grails. However when I reach the step where I need to move my dependencies from the BuildConfig.groovy to the build.gradle file. I have no experience with gradle, at all. I've tried to look up some basic information on them to figure out where all of my dependencies are going to go, but I get mixed information.

(Just for information sake, **IntelliJ 15** is the primary IDE that's being used on this project)

Is there a simple guide for this conversion? Or at least a Gradle guide that will point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just read gradle documentation to see how this tool is working. Part about dependency management is [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html)

Then you must include all your dependencies in `build.gradle` file.
Keep in mind that if you use any plugin in your application you must use it version compatible with Gradle 3.

Comment: Thanks! I'm still working on updating the project to grails 3, but this did help.